# AJAX GET doesent work from SVG file

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg, get, semantic-ui

I try to make an AJAX request from and SVG that contains `data-html`, I used the [`Semantic UI Popup`](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html),

The request works if i call it outside the SVG, but doesent work if it is inside the SVG (inide the `data-html`), the test, is just a simple:

```
$("#mini").click(function(){
            $.get("/", function(data, status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
        });
```

If `#mini` is outside the SVG, I get the response, but not when it is inside.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vx59te34/4/

The area to test is: [image: area]

Comment: Are you writing JS inside a SVG file? Is it me, or is SVG supposed to be just an image format?

Comment: @JeremyThille the svg is an svg tag inside an html, and the js is external

Comment: why don't you just post your HTML code, instead of describing it? :)

Comment: i updated the question with the fiddle

Comment: Oh man, I see what you mean. `data-html="<h1 id='mini'>hiiii</h1>"` is just data. That is, a _string_. You can't select it as part of the DOM, for it is not a DOM element. It's just a word, stored in a `"data-html"` attribute. You can access this string using `$("#Illizi").data('html')`, but it will remain a string. It's nothing you can select and bind a click to.

Comment: ah! so the solution is to use `$("path").click(function(event) { do_something(event.target.id);});` and send it to an external function to send it as ajax?

Comment: In that case, you can do : `data-target='#mini'` , and then `$("path").click(function() { $( $(this).data('target') );})` and it should select `$('#mini')`.

Comment: so the `#mini` will be outside the svg?

Comment: Of course. The SVG is a picture. It's not a container. Wrap a div around, that will contain both the SVG and #mini.

Comment: can you put an aswer so i can validate it ^_^

Comment: @JeremyThille there is `<foreignObject>`  that can embeed html inside svg, but it will be another head-break https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: I didn't know about the foreignObject, but I think it's much simple to do it the regulat way :) I have compiled my comments in one answer, if you want to upvote and accept it I would be grateful.

Comment: of course i will do, thank you again ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-html="<h1 id='mini'>hiiii</h1>"` is just data. That is, a string. You can't select it as part of the DOM, for it is not a DOM element. It's just a word, stored in a `"data-html"` attribute. You can access this string using `$("#Illizi").data('html')`, but it will remain a string. It's nothing you can select and bind a click to.

In that case, you can do : `data-target='#mini'` , and then `$("path").click(function() { $( $(this).data('target') );})` and it should select `$('#mini')`.

The SVG is a picture. It's not a container. Wrap a div around, that will contain both the SVG and #mini.